# Request in Rails Testing not returning body

Tags: ruby-on-rails, request, integration-testing

I'm starting to do some testing to my app in rails, and following official tutorial, I've written this:

```
class UserFlowTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
    def login
        post ns_login_user_path, { :user => { :username => 'user', :password => 'password' } }
        assert_response 200
    end

    test "should complete a flow" do
        login
        post create_participant_path(:event_id => events(:myevent).id), {
            :format     => :json,
            :event_role => event_roles(:regular_participant).id,
            :in_team    => true
        }
        r = JSON.parse(response.body)
        assert_response 200
        puts "response creating participation #{r.as_json}"
        participant_id = r[:participant_id]
    end
end
```

It does the login OK, but after that, when trying to create the participant, `response` is a variable with no `.body` attribute, just the number 200 (the status), so the `JSON.parse` method crashes.

This is the relevant part of my `routes.rb`:

```
# Events
scope 'events', :controller => :events do
    # some routes
    scope ':event_id', :controller => :events do
        # some routes
        scope 'participants', :controller => :participants do
            post '', :action => :create_participant, :as => :create_participant
            # some routes
        end
    end
end
```

And the controller `ParticipantsController.rb`:

```
class ParticipantsController < ApiController

    before_action :require_login, :only => [:create_participant, :update_participant]

    # Creates a participation of a person in the event
    # Receives the following params:
    # - +event_id+
    # - +in_team+::_boolean
    # - +event_role+
    def create_participant
        # … some logic
        if participant.save
            render :status => :ok, :json => Hash[
                :participant_id      => participant.id,
                :team_participant_id => participant.team_participant_id
            ]
        else
            render :status => 406, :json => Hash[
                :message => t('alerts.error_saving'),
                :errors  => participant.errors.as_json
            ]
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the full response object on controller specs, but looking at [the code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/aecf182a4b660cc2925bba11e06ba187723d63e4/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/testing/integration.rb#L392), it appears that the `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest` code only returns the `response.status`, not the entire response object.

[The documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/IntegrationTest.html) doesn't directly say that you can access the response object. You might try doing a `render_views` and see if that makes any difference, but based on inspection of the code, it doesn't seem like it will.